# Desktop push notification?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, push-notification

I want to send the desktop notification to my customer dynamical from the server side. For example I have one website based on the e-commerce platform. I want to send the desktop notification to my customer what are the new offers are available. I created the notification with following code.. But I want to call the notification without any user activity.

```
$(window).load(function(){
        if(!window.Notification){
            console.log('sorry Notification not supported');
        }
        else {
            Notification.requestPermission(function(p){
                if(p === 'denied') {

                } else if(p === 'granted') {

                } else {

                }
                console.log(p);
            });
        }


        var notify;
        if(Notification.permission === 'default') {
            console.log('Please allow Notification');
        } else {
            notify = new Notification('Cashback Notification..',{
                body : 'Get assured cashback on purchases made via Getex.com',
                icon : 'images/notification_getex.png'

            });


        }
});
```

Here i trigger notification only for the window load, but i want to notify from  the server side like execute or call any API link. 
Please help me Thanks!

Comment: here you are generating a local notification.

Comment: if you want to implement push notification, checkout this firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: another way to do it is through webpush library: https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push

Comment: We can send desktop notification to respective customer right?

Comment: @ambernemani You have any examples for the dynamic call notification?

Comment: i had implemented a sample app and a nodejs server simulator using web push, you need to create service worker at client side which will help in receiving push notification even when your web page is not open